# how to iterate over a growing set in java

Tags: java, c++, iterator, set, hashset

I have some code in c++ in which a set is iterated which is growing with each loop.

Sample c++ code is as below.
How can I write the same code in java?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define tr(c,i) for(auto i=(c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++)
#define rep(i,n) for(int i=0;i<(n);i++)
#define forup(i,a,b) for(int i=(a);i<=(b);i++)
#define tcsolve() int tcs; cin >> tcs; forup(tc, 1, tcs) solve();

void solve() {
    int n, k, t, ans;
    cin >> n >> k;
    set<int> s, w;
    rep (i, n) {
        cin >> t;
        s.insert(t);
    }
    ans = k;
    w.insert(k);
    tr(s, i) {
        tr(w, j) {
            int x = *i^*j;
            ans = max(ans, x);
            w.insert(x);
        }
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
}

int main () {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    tcsolve();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to do the same thing in java

```
tr(w, j) {
    int x = *i^*j;
    ans = max(ans, x);
    w.insert(x);
}
```

How can I do this?

My solution is something like this

```
static int findMaximum(Set<Integer> set, int k) 
    {
        int ans = k;
        Set<Integer> temp = new HashSet<>();

        temp.add(k);

        Iterator<Integer> iter_i = set.iterator();
        Iterator<Integer> iter_j = temp.iterator();

        int i,j=0;
        while(iter_i.hasNext())
        {
            i = (int)iter_i.next();
            while(iter_j.hasNext())
            {
                j = (int)iter_j.next();
                int x = i^j;
                ans = Integer.max(ans, x);
                temp.add(x);
            }
            System.out.println("temp: " +temp);
            System.out.println("i: " + i +" j: " +j);
        }

        return ans;

    }
```

But my actual answer is

```
temp: [4, 5]
i: 1 j: 4
temp: [4, 5]
i: 2 j: 4
temp: [4, 5]
i: 3 j: 4
5
```

while in the correct solution the set should increase with the return value of the method as `7`

Please point out if there is any other error in my problem

Comment: It's not very clear from the question what exactly you're trying to do. Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes there is basic error. In Java you cannot add or delete elements into/from Collection (HashSet is one of it) while iterating through it. It throws Concurrent Modification Exception.

Comment: @Vadim Not necessarily. Depends on the collection type, iterator type, and how you're adding.

Comment: A note on the C++ code. Don't feel bad if you have trouble reading it. It follows idioms that reduce readability and portability are not recommended for professional programming. Learn what you can from the algorithm, but don't write code like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should not reimplement it. You can use Java Streams, they have already implement it.

This is just an example:

```
Integer maxNumber = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
                    .max(Comparator.comparing(Integer::valueOf)).get();
Integer minNumber = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
                    .min(Comparator.comparing(Integer::valueOf)).get();

System.out.println("maxNumber = " + maxNumber);
System.out.println("minNumber = " + minNumber);
```

To create an Stream from a Set:

```
Set<Integer> s = ...
Integer max = s.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Integer::valueOf)).get();
```